# Automatic numbering of rows in attribute table fails

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I'm working on a big data set, with 385'000 features. Each feature is the centroid of a polygon, and I'd like to assign a value to each of them. I've used the `@row_number`in the field calculator to do so (QGIS 3.10). It works perfectly until the row 235'262 and then for not apparent reason, the following row is labelled "NULL". Any insight on what I may be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the Field Calculator has a limit on the number of features it can update. Try selecting the rows that didn't get a value (use the tool `select by expression` with the expression `"yourfieldname" is NULL`), then use the Field Calculator again, with the same calculation and tick the box for "apply changes to selected features only".

Comment: What version of QQIS are you using?

Comment: What properties have the field you are updating ? it could be a limitation of the field type or properties (for exemple the short integer data type have a max value of 32,767)

Comment: @J.R the properties of the field are: whole number (integer), Length: 6

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted this out using a different method. I saved my dataset into a Geopackage, and has automatically created a `fid` field. Row 1 now has 1 in the `fid` field such as in the picture below:

[image]